# Solve for $y$: $\frac{y+1}{y-1} = 10^{x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

Can someone please show me the steps (all of them… yeah, even the obvious ones)
to go from

$$\begin{align}\frac{y+1}{y-1} = 10^{x^2}\end{align}$$

to

$$\begin{align}y=\frac{10^{x^2}+1}{10^{x^2}-1}\end{align}$$

Comment: This is basically the fact that the function $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x-1}$ is inverse to itself. This can be seen quite well from the graph: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+y%3D%28x%2B1%29%2F%28x-1%29

Answer (score 3):

Solve for $y$:

> $$\frac{y+1}{y-1} = 10^{x^2}$$

Multiply both sides by $y-1$:
$$y+1=10^{x^2}(y-1)$$
Expand out terms of the right hand side:
$$y+1=10^{x^2}y-10^{x^2}$$
Subtract $1+10^{x^2}y$ from both sides:
$$y(1-10^{x^2})=-1-10^{x^2}$$
Divide both sides by $1-10^{x^2}$
$$\boxed{\color{blue}{y=\frac{10^{x^2}+1}{10^{x^2}-1}}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{y+1}{y-1} = 10^{x^2}$$

$$y+1 = 10^{x^2}(y-1)$$

$$y+1 = 10^{x^2}y-10^{x^2}$$

$$y+1+10^{x^2} = 10^{x^2}y$$

$$1+10^{x^2} = (10^{x^2}-1)y$$

$$y=\frac{10^{x^2}+1}{10^{x^2}-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

For $y\neq1$
$$\frac{y+1}{y-1}=10^{x^2}$$ $$y+1=y\cdot10^{x^2}-10^{x^2}$$ $$1+10^{x^2}=y(10^{x^2}-1 )$$

Then?